# How to see values of dynamic arrays in Visual Studio debugger

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-debugging

I have pointer to pointer array like

```
int **matrix = new int*[NUMROW];
for (int i=0;i<NUMROW;i++)
  matrix[i] = new int [NUMCOL];
for (int row=0;row<8;row++)
  for (int col=0;col<17;col++)
       matrix[row][col] = rand ();
```

When I run the code in the debugger I can see only the first value of the array.

How can I see all of the array in the debugger like I can see on static array?

Comment: The simple answer is *you can't*. The reason is that neither the compiler nor the debugger knows how large the data you allocated is.

Comment: add watch `matrix[row][col]`. maybe you can try to watch the matrix pointer + an offest of size int

Comment: Also, why are you using pointers? When you think "dynamic array" you should always next think [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: i use dibaim for practis and i not seccess to see all the value

Answer (score 3):

in the watch window you can enter e.g. `array, 100` to display the 100 first elements in `array`

you can extend this to any pointerexpression: `array + someInt + 13, 3` to get the three elements starting at `array + someInt + 13`

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl+Alt+W, 1 to call the "Watch" window. Or select Debug -> Window -> Watch -> (any of the watch windows)

Then type in any expression as you want, such as `matrix[row][col]`

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic array the simpliest way is to add into Watch list of your debugger vars:

```
array[0]
array[1]
array[-any-index-you-need-here-]
matrix[0][4]
```

and so on

Comment: I not get you How can i see the value oonpointer to pointer array

Comment: @dani1999 do you know what is Watch list for debugger?

Comment: dani1999 do like @BeyelerStudios said

Comment: I not get do what he said...   where is watch windows?  The black windows that open when i put the input?...if yes i cant write there what he said...

Comment: @dani1999 Are you using Visual Studio?